# Clustering Hyper-V with Server 2012 - MPIO Version Mismatch

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012, windows-cluster, hyper-v-server-2012

I've done a fair bit of searching around online and am having a lot of trouble finding info regarding how to upgrade the Microsoft DSM for MPIO.

I have two nearly identical servers, both with fresh installs of Server 2012 Datacenter on them. I'm using a HP Storageworks x1600 over iSCSI for shared storage.

I'm following this guide to get the cluster up and going: http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2012/12/12/step-by-step-building-a-free-hyper-v-server-2012-cluster-part-1-of-2.aspx#.UQqUOFrm2DA

I'm to the point where I run the "Test-Cluster -Node NodeName,NodeName" command. It gets to the part where it tests the redundancy of storage and fails saying that the versions of the DSM must be the same. Both OS are fully patched. Can I simply copy a DSM over from one server to another? If so, how would I go about finding it?

Answer (score 1):

HP recommends that you use the native DSM module for Windows Server 2012 and above, so two things you may want to check are, first, on each computer have you installed the Multipath-IO, you can do that with (using an Administrator PowerShell window):

`Add-WindowsFeature Multipath-IO`

And once that has been done, run `mpiocpl.exe` (the MPIO GUI) and check that "Add support for iSCSI devices" is checked and then click "Add". See here (taken on a machine that doesn't use MPIO):

[image: MPIO Properties dialogue box, showing the check boxes for 'Add support for iSCSI devices' and 'Add support for SAS devices']

A final step you can run, which is recommended in an HP support document on StorageWorks but *may not be necessary in 2012*, is to run the following command on each server:

`mpclaim -n -i -a`

The `-n` option suppresses reboot, `-i` is to install MPIO support on device(s), and `-a` specifies all applicable devices.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. Fixed it after enabling "update for other products" and compleate updating I've got identical versions of Microsoft DSM